# how to get cross references for multiple items Persian language

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, xepersian

I would like to get a cross reference for multiple items using `cleveref`, but the problem is with that "and"; it shoould be "و".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand\pcref[1]{(\cref{#1})}
\crefformat{table}{#2جدول~#1#3}
\crefformat{figure}{#2شكل~#1#3}
\crefname{figure}{الشكل}{الأشكال}
\Crefname{figure}{الشكل}{الأشكال}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=2]{Arial}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!] \caption{foo}\label{tab:foo}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{foo}\label{fig:foo1}\end{figure}
\pcref{tab:foo}, \pcref{fig:foo,fig:foo1}, \pcref{fig:foo,tab:foo}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the instruction

```
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{ و }
```

in order to achieve your formatting objective. See p. 14 of the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) of the `cleveref` package for more information about the `\crefpairconjunction` macro. There, you'll find the following explanation:

> `\crefpairconjunction` is used when there are only two cross-references in the list ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand\pcref[1]{(\cref{#1})}
\newcommand\crefpairconjunction{ و } % <-- new
\crefformat{table}{#2جدول~#1#3}
\crefformat{figure}{#2شكل~#1#3}
\crefname{figure}{الشكل}{الأشكال}
\Crefname{figure}{الشكل}{الأشكال}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=2]{Arial}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]  \caption{tabbar} \label{tab:bar}\end{table}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{figfoo1}\label{fig:foo}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[h!] \caption{figfoo2}\label{fig:foo1}\end{figure}

\pcref{tab:bar}, \pcref{fig:foo,fig:foo1}, \pcref{fig:foo,tab:bar}
\end{document}
```